# create multiple copies of a file in java with different names

Tags: java

I want to create multiple copies of a file(with some data) in java with different names. I'm a beginner, so i don't know much about java. I have created the same code in c++.

can anyone help?

Comment: The file to be copied is previously created and having some data, or you just try to make some files with different names?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a file with some data and you want to make more copies of it with different name, you can use `Files class copy()` method to copy file in java.  It uses File System providers to copy the files. It will work on Java 7 or higher.

```
  File source = new File("text.txt");

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {            // where n is the no. of copies to make
    File dest = new File("text" + i +".txt");
    try {
        dest.createNewFile();
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + ex);
    }
  }
```

There are many ways to copy content of file into other to make multiple copies of a file. [Check them here](http://www.journaldev.com/861/java-copy-file)

Comment: instead of thanking you should follow [good answer rule](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
    File source = new File("/home/java/Downloads/tableDocx/renameFilesName/docxwithnewcode.docx"); // Change this to the source .docx file path
    int n = 200; // Set the number of copies to make

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String destinationFileName = "/home/java/Downloads/tableDocx/renameFilesName/a/document" + i + ".docx"; // Change the destination file name to keep the same name
        File dest = new File(destinationFileName);
        try {
            Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception = " + ex);
        }
        System.out.println("CREADTED");
    }
```